# Liferay 7.0 Data Migration from one database to another

Tags: mysql, hsqldb, liferay-7

I'm using Liferay 7.0 with the Default Database(HSQL DB) and have many sites,pages and users in it. I'm trying to configure the portal to access mySql DB and it worked. 
But, I want all the Content in the previous Database in the newly configured mySql Database and Database Migration in Server Administration doesn't work. How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is to use import/export capabilities provided by liferay. If the servers use the same liferay version, you will be able to export your content, using the site publish tab. ps: one should not use the default database in production.

Comment: So, there is no way to migrate data from the default Database to mySQL database using the migration provided by the Liferay?

Comment: not using that tool. I would start with export/import, you will this this option scattered in the "control panel" areas, even system setting has an export option (although its mechanics is a bit different)

Answer (score 1):

Database Migration tool in server administration was deprecated, but by mistake, its user interface wasn't removed.

That user interface will be removed in future versions, more info see: https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-75551